# Mismatch between characters put and read

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream, ofstream

I'm trying to write a Huffman encoder but I'm getting some compression errors. I identified the problem as mismatches between characters that were put() to the ofstream and the characters read() from the same file.

One specific instance of this problem :

- The put() writes ASCII character 10 (Line feed)
- The read() reads ASCII character 13 (Carriage return)

I thought read and put read and write raw data ( no character translations ) I'm not sure why this is happening. Can someone help me out?

Here is the ofstream instance for writing the compressed file:

```
std::ofstream compressedFileStream(getCompressedFileName(),std::ios::binary||std::ios::ate);
```

and the ifstream instance for reading the same

```
    std::ifstream fileInput(getFileName()+".huf",std::ios::binary);
```

The code is running on Windows 7 and all streams in the program are opened in binary mode.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Can you post the code that opens the `ofstream` instances.

Comment: Most likely you've a problem of binary/text file mismatch.

Comment: @6502 How is that possible if all streams everywhere are opened in binary mode ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not opening in binary mode due to a typo:

```
std::ofstream compressedFileStream(getCompressedFileName(),std::ios::binary||std::ios::ate)
```

should be:

```
std::ofstream compressedFileStream(getCompressedFileName(),std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate)
                                                                      //   ^
```

`|`, not `||`.

Answer (score 3):

The symptoms show that you are creating the ofsteam with text mode or you are creating it using a filedesc that is opened in text mode. 
You will want to pass ios::binary to it at construction time or it may run in text mode on Windows.

After you added the code, the reason proves to be a typo;

```
std::ios::binary||std::ios::ate
```

should be

```
std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you are writing binary data, you need to open the file with the appropriate attributes.

Similarly, if you are reading binary data, you need to open the file with the appropriate attributes.

Comment: All my streams are in binary mode.

Comment: No - they're not.  Or, since I can't actually see the code, let's put it at "I'd be very, very surprised if they were both binary streams".  You would not be getting the CR to LF mapping occurring if they were both binary.  I think it is more likely that the trouble is with the output stream; you seem to be seeing the CR of CRLF that was generated when you put the newline to a text stream on Windows.  The symptom is exactly characteristic of using a text stream to write what should be binary data.  Maybe you can show us the code that opens the output stream - and the input stream?

Comment: I have put the code in the question, but it seems that there was a typo that hmjd pointed out , I'll correct that and check if the program works.